# Is is possible to group "hard disk drives" in Windows 7 by actual physical drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I have 3 physical drives installed/attached (2 internal and one over USB). I'd like to easily see which "hard disk drive" (in Win 7's "Computer" window) lies on which actual hard disk drive, or rather, which partitions lie on the same drive.

I know I can see this in "Disk Management" or with 3rd party tools such as Norton Partition Magic or Acronis Disk Director Suite (I'm using the latter).  But that's a lot more complicated than I want it (I don't need all the details these tools give me, not for a rough/quick overview).

Or maybe there's some utility out there that can replace Win7's built-in overview window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not set a label on the hard drive which identifies disk a drive is on.  That way it will show in Explorer.  You can also change the drive letters in Disk Management so the drives letters are grouped together to get the order correct.

Comment: Exactly. Just rename them. I was thinking the same thing when I was reading the question, but before I saw your answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Windows is all about abstracting away these things. I don't think there's a way of viewing partitions by physical drive in windows explorer.

The only way of doing so is via Computer Manager or perhaps some 3rd party tool.